# Libgdx AndroidGraphics pause flag never be set to false

Tags: android, libgdx, glsurfaceview

Hi I come into a problem when AndroidGraphics pause.
Say I have a libgdx fragment in a scroll view. When I scroll the fragment outside of the screen and the libgdx will stop render. and then I go to another activity and the pasue method of AndroidGraphics will be called. In this method

```
while (pause) {
try {
// TODO: fix deadlock race condition with quick resume/pause.
// Temporary workaround:
// Android ANR time is 5 seconds, so wait up to 4 seconds before assuming
// deadlock and killing process. This can easily be triggered by opening the
// Recent Apps list and then double-tapping the Recent Apps button with
// ~500ms between taps.
synch.wait(4000);
if (pause) {
// pause will never go false if onDrawFrame is never called by the GLThread
// when entering this method, we MUST enforce continuous rendering
Gdx.app.error(LOG_TAG, "waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing");
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
} catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
Gdx.app.log(LOG_TAG, "waiting for pause synchronization failed!");
}
}
```

It waits for pause to be set to false, but the libgdx surfaceview is outside of the screen and the onDrawFrame will never be called so the

```
Gdx.app.error(LOG_TAG, "waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing");
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

will be execute. so that my app crash. How to solve this?

Comment: This "temporary workaround" has been in place for five or more years in the source code. I suggest opening an issue on the libgdx github page.

Comment: @Tenfour04 So what is the temporary workaround? I have opened a issue in GitHub of libgdx

Comment: I don't know what the deadlock condition is that they're talking about, so I don't know a safe alternative to what theyre doing here.

Comment: Hi there, I met the same problem. Do you remember the solution of this?